# i have pushed my website locally on github after creating an empty repository but the repository is still blank

Tags: github

I have a folder with codes, i pushed it on github after creating a repository but the process was successful but i can not see any file in the repository, any help guys, this is my cli codes

```
SydoTech@DESKTOP-PUHK97G MINGW64 /d/james/ict-specialists (master)
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/Kato669/ict-specialist-website.git

SydoTech@DESKTOP-PUHK97G MINGW64 /d/james/ict-specialists (master)
$ git push origin main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Kato669/ict-specialist-website.git'

SydoTech@DESKTOP-PUHK97G MINGW64 /d/james/ict-specialists (master)
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 1383, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1383/1383), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1380/1380), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (1383/1383), 35.93 MiB | 323.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1383 (delta 181), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

SydoTech@DESKTOP-PUHK97G MINGW64 /d/james/ict-specialists (master)
$
```

Comment: Have you committed? git commit -m "initial commit"

Comment: I would also add git add . to include all files, then git commit. Here is one liner: `git commit -am "initial commit"`

Comment: i commited it and added everything with a period